# Actionscript 3: How to access an object after adding it as child to another?

Tags: actionscript, parent-child, sprite

I have a problem regarding zoom functionality. I simply cannot access my sprite anymore after I've added it as child to another sprite.

Here is the relevant part of my code (ask for more if you need to)

If I try to scale the bg_image in my init function, before the line `spImage.addChild(bg_image);`, there are no complications. However I simply cannot edit the bg_image's properties after this line (the zoom function, for example)

Please help!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import fl.controls.Button;
import fl.controls.List;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

import flash.display.Shape;
import fl.transitions.Fly;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    // Zoom

    public static var scale:Number = 1;

    public var spImage:Sprite;
    public var mat:Matrix;
    public var mcIn:MovieClip;
    public var mcOut:MovieClip;

    public var board:Sprite;
    public var boardWidth:int = 980;
    public var boardHeight:int = 661;
    public var boardMask:Shape;

    public var externalCenter:Point;
    public var internalCenter:Point;

    public const scaleFactor:Number = 0.8;
    public var minScale:Number = 0.25;
    public var maxScale:Number = 10.0;

    public var bg_image:Sprite;

            public function Main()
    {
                    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            }

    public function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        bg_image = new Image();

        this.graphics.beginFill(0xB6DCF4);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,boardWidth,boardHeight);
        this.graphics.endFill();

        spImage = new Sprite();
        this.addChild(spImage);

        boardMask = new Shape();
        boardMask.graphics.beginFill(0xDDDDDD);
        boardMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,boardWidth,boardHeight);
        boardMask.graphics.endFill();
        boardMask.x = 0;
        boardMask.y = 0;
        this.addChild(boardMask);
        spImage.mask = boardMask;

        minScale = boardWidth / bg_image.width;

        mcIn = new InCursorClip();
        mcOut = new OutCursorClip();

        bg_image.addChild(mcIn);
        bg_image.addChild(mcOut);

        bg_image.scaleX = minScale;
        bg_image.scaleY = minScale;

        spImage.addChild(bg_image);
        spImage.addChild(mcIn);
        spImage.addChild(mcOut);

        spImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

        spImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoom);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

        spImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }

    private function startDragging(mev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        spImage.startDrag();
    }

    private function stopDragging(mev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        spImage.stopDrag();
    }

    public function zoom(mev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if ((!mev.shiftKey)&&(!mev.ctrlKey))
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((mev.shiftKey)&&(mev.ctrlKey))
        {
            return;
        }

        externalCenter = new Point(spImage.mouseX,spImage.mouseY);
        internalCenter = new Point(bg_image.mouseX,bg_image.mouseY);

        if (mev.shiftKey)
        {
            bg_image.scaleX = Math.max(scaleFactor*bg_image.scaleX, minScale);
            bg_image.scaleY = Math.max(scaleFactor*bg_image.scaleY, minScale);

        }
        if (mev.ctrlKey)
        {
            bg_image.scaleX = Math.min(1/scaleFactor*bg_image.scaleX, maxScale);
            bg_image.scaleY = Math.min(1/scaleFactor*bg_image.scaleY, maxScale);
        }

        mat = this.transform.matrix.clone();

        MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalCenter,externalCenter);

        bg_image.transform.matrix = mat;
    }




    private function keyHandler(ke:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        mcIn.x = spImage.mouseX;
        mcIn.y = spImage.mouseY;
        mcOut.x = spImage.mouseX;
        mcOut.y = spImage.mouseY;

        mcIn.visible = ke.ctrlKey;
        mcOut.visible = ke.shiftKey;

        if (ke.ctrlKey || ke.shiftKey)
        {
            Mouse.hide();
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean you can't access the properties? Do you get an exception? Can you post the exception?

Comment: I fixed it! mat = this.transform.matrix.clone(); -> this should be replaced by bg_image. THanks for response btw